# UpdateView don't redirect to success_url defined in my class-based view

Tags: django, django-views

When I make a post in a update view this redirect to another url but not to that I want. I have an application called `project`.
This is my `project.urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('edit/<int:pk>', ProjectUpdateView.as_view(), name='project_update'),
    path('detail/<int:pk>', ProjectDetailView.as_view(), name='project_detail'),
    ...
]
```

And this is my `views.py`:

```
class ProjectUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Project
    ...

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('project_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

And my `models.py`:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('project_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

When I make a post to this url `/edit/5` this redirects me to `/edit` and this page return me a 404 error, of course because this url doesn't exist.
how can i fix this? I'm using django 2.0

**Update**
this is my template `project_edit.html`:

```
<form method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type='submit' class='btn'>Aceoptar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with your `get_success_url` or get_absolute_url` methods.

It sounds like your form action is:

```
<form method="post" action=".">
```

Since you are posting from `/edit/5` (without a trailing slash), this means that you are posting to `/edit/`.

You could change it to:

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

or reverse the url

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'project_update' project.pk %}">
```